# Are App Installs From Facebook Analytics supposed to be triggered when users update the app?

Tags: ios, facebook, installation, analytics, facebook-analytics

I have tried to look for this but cannot find this in the documentation.

I saw that with by installing a different version in Testflight, the App Install event is being logged in the Analytics. However, I'm not sure if it will also be logged once the users **update** the app in the **Appstore**, of if it just logs when users **Installs** (by previously uninstalling the app)

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general our SDK is smart enough to avoid sending duplicate install events including App re-launches and upgrades. To be crystal clear Install event is really a first app launch event on the device. To avoid duplication we store some flag in app internal storage indicating did we successfully sent the install already. Saying that, in rare cases, such as when App package name was changed or internal store was cleared or some when this flag was not carried during upgrade, our SDK will attempt to send again new install event. Lastly, we have a proper dedup logic for SDK installs on our backend (App Version is not playing a role here).

Answer (score 1):

The App Install event is only triggered once on the first launch of the App. After that, the App Launch event will be triggered. It will not track an app update as a new App Install event. Check the automatic App Event collection definitions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/automatic-event-collection-detail).

Comment: Thanks. But will that mean that if I included FB SDK in a new version (i.e. 2.0) all the users who upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0 will log App Installs? And then from there no more?

Comment: @ReinaldoVerdugo @Elize’s answer elaborates on this. The App Version being changed does not trigger the App Install event again after the first time it’s called. Along with deduplication logic for SDK installs on the backend, this is accounted for.